# HTTP Redirection in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted an ASP.NET web application on my IIS server. And I have used HTTP redirection of my default website to one specific page of my application.
Below is screenshot:

Now when I go to the page in my browser (Google Chrome), the login page is displayed. But when I log in and after that when I click on any button of my application's homepage, my session expires. Why does this happens?

This is the problem in Chrome browser. Works well on Firefox and IE. Suggest me some solution so that I can use my application.

[image: IIS]

Comment: Compare the requests made by FF and IE with Chrome

Comment: Why do you need to redirect in the first place? That feature should be used with great caution.

Comment: How I can compare requests made by FF and IE with chrome?

Comment: I just want to know why my session expires in google chrome only not in other browser?